# How do I apply a command to all OpTeX slides?

Tags: slideshow, optex

OpTeX has a built-in set of macros for slideshows. I like the API a lot, but not so much the design of it.

In particular, I am trying to:

- use blue for hyperlinks,
- Use a different colour (say red) for titles,
- Increase the font size.

```
\slides \wideformat \slideshow

% Customization
\_let\_scolor=\Red
\_typosize[18/21]
\hyperlinks\Blue\Blue

\tit \OpTeX/
\subtit John Doe

\pg;
\sec Useful links
* Wikipedia: \url{https://wikipedia.org}
* DuckDuckGo: \url{https://duckduckgo.org}

\pg.
```

However, only the first slide is affected by the three commands I wrote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [documented](http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/op-slides.pdf), the command `\slideshow` must be the *last* command in the decleration part of the document. Thus your document should be as follows:

```
\slides \wideformat 

% Customization
\_let\_scolor=\Red
\_typosize[18/21]
\hyperlinks\Blue\Blue

\slideshow


\tit \OpTeX/
\subtit John Doe

\pg;
\sec Useful links
* Wikipedia: \url{https://wikipedia.org}
* DuckDuckGo: \url{https://duckduckgo.org}

\pg.
```

[image]